# Getting the Sum of the Contents of Rows

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a column with dollar amounts, such as:

```
$1.00
$4.00
$100.00
```

and so on. These values are put into the column by calculating the % of another column. I want to get the sum of all the dollar amounts of that column. I cant use Sum(data) because its static data in the column. Is there a way to get the sum easily?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by static data? can you try using this in your query - '$' + sum(CAST(replace(data,'$','') As decimal))

Comment: static wasn't the right word to use. what I mean is the amounts in that column don't come from the dataset. So I can't use the Sum(dataset value) I have to add them some other way.

Comment: can you show us your query or sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to deal with this:

1. If it's the same percentage being applied to each row, sum the original column and apply the same percentage to that sum.
2. If the original source of the data is from a database, do the percent calculation in your Dataset's SQL query, then use the Sum function in your Tablix as usual.

If these don't apply, you'll need to give more detailed information about your problem.